# Changing a labels visibility using PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt

I have created a form in QtDesigner and converted it into a python document using PyQt. In my QtDesigner document I have added the label that reads "You have successfully sent in the form". What I want to do is hide this label until the submit button has been clicked. I'm struggling because of the complex format of the PyQt document.

This is the code for submit and label (submitButton, label_3):

```
self.submitButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
self.submitButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("submitButton"))
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.submitButton)
class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
def setupUi(self, Form):
self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
    self.label_3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QLabel\n"
"{\n"
"   font: bold 14pt \"helvetica\";\n"
"   color: darkgreen;\n"
"}"))
    self.label_3.setScaledContents(False)
    self.label_3.setWordWrap(False)
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
    self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
```

Here's roughly what i'm doing (codes is wrong, I know, but hopefully it helps you understand my problem.

```
label_3.hide() == True
if submitButton.clicked
    label_3.show() == True
```

Comment: instead of label_3.hide() have you tried label_3.close() ? that should hopefully work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From where are you pasting these two code snippets? In your MainWindow init? Whatever it is, you probably want to hide the button right after it is created:

```
self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
self.label_3.hide()
```

And connect the button's [clicked signal](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractButton.html?highlight=clicked#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractButton.clicked) to the label's show() method:

```
self.submitButton.clicked.connect(self.label_3.show)
```